# variable can't assign from subscribe method

Tags: javascript, angular

Within the method itself Shows the value, but outside it shows undefined message

Ubigeo.service.ts

```
 lisProvinciaByDepartamento( ubigeoId: string): Observable<Ubigeo[]> {
    let ubigeo$ = this.http
    .get(`${this.baseUrl}/provincia/${ubigeoId}`, {headers: this.getHeaders()})
    .map(mapUbigeos)
    .catch(handleError);
    return ubigeo$;
}
```

Detail.component.ts

```
cargaPronvicia(ubigeoId: string) {
    this._ubigeoService
        .lisProvinciaByDepartamento(ubigeoId)
        .subscribe((p) => {
            this.provinciaSeleccionada = p
                .find(item =>
                    item.ubigeoId.substr(2, 2) === ubigeoId.substr(2, 2));
            this.provincias = p;
            console.log(this.provinciaSeleccionada); //2
        });

    console.log(this.provinciaSeleccionada); //1
}
```

[undefined in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GnNqv.png)

Comment: It's because your variable is an observable so there isn't a value inside of `this.provinciaSeleccionada` when you log it the first time

Comment: You should avoid mixing promises and observables because that would defeat the purpose of observables. See @Aravind 's answer

Comment: @Aravind Meant to but forgot, sorry. Upvoted

Comment: Cool. @GabrieleB-David happy coding :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its because the data retrieval is relatively **async** when you are using it as observalbes.
So never use the variable directly,

**Good practices**

1. Skip subscription if it is empty.

   ```
   cargaPronvicia(ubigeoId: string) {
      this._ubigeoService
       .lisProvinciaByDepartamento(ubigeoId)
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
       .skipWhile((p) => p === undefined)
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
       .subscribe((p) => {
           this.provinciaSeleccionada = p
               .find(item =>
                   item.ubigeoId.substr(2, 2) === ubigeoId.substr(2, 2));
           this.provincias = p;
           console.log(this.provinciaSeleccionada); //2
       });

   console.log(this.provinciaSeleccionada); //1
   }
   ```
2. Where ever you are using the subscribed variables, check if it contains data, an example in your case would be

   ```
   if(this.provinciaSeleccionada){
       console.log(this.provinciaSeleccionada);
   }
   ```

**Update 1:**

- Use promises with most care, reason is **when you are using promises in constructor, your component will not load until the promise is resolved**.

  - By this speed of the application will be as expected.
  - Angular2's reactive nature is not utilized.

Comment: Isako Upvote too if this helped you. :) Happy coding